# Google Maps works, but then displays gey tiles when drawing geopoints

Tags: android, google-maps, google-api

I'm trying to create an app to plot our mountain bike trails on a Google map. I've got the Google map part working. However, once I try to plot a couple of geopoints and connect them it does displays the geopoints and connects them, but the Google map stops displaying. Only grey tiles show. Here is my code before I plot the points which works.

```
public class DPHTmaps extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapController mMapController;
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapController = mapView.getController();
        mMapController.setZoom(18);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I change my code to this to plot and connect a couple of geopoint and it turns map tiles grey.

```
public class DPHTmaps extends MapActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        MapController mMapController;
        MapView mapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.mapview);
        mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        mMapController = mapView.getController();
        mMapController.setZoom(18);
        // Two points in Backside trail
        GeoPoint point1 = new GeoPoint(-91777756,43311836);
        GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint(-91777627,43311718);
        mMapController.setCenter(point2);
        // Pass the geopoints to the overlay class
        MapOverlay mapOvlay = new MapOverlay(point1, point2);
        mapView.getOverlays().add(mapOvlay);
    }

    public class MapOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {
        private GeoPoint mGpt1;
        private GeoPoint mGpt2;
        protected MapOverlay(GeoPoint gp1, GeoPoint gp2 ) {
            mGpt1 = gp1;
            mGpt2 = gp2;
        }
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            Paint paint;
            paint = new Paint();
            paint.setColor(Color.RED);
            paint.setAntiAlias(true);
            paint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
            paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
            Point pt1 = new Point();
            Point pt2 = new Point();
            Projection projection = mapView.getProjection();
            projection.toPixels(mGpt1, pt1);
            projection.toPixels(mGpt2, pt2);
            canvas.drawLine(pt1.x, pt1.y, pt2.x, pt2.y, paint);
            return true;
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }
```

This has been driving me nuts. I've looked for a solution for a 2 weeks and have found nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could it be as simple as the fact that you are passing the lat/lon to the GeoPoint constructor in the wrong order?  You need to pass the latitude first, and based on the fact that -91 is not a valid latitude, I'm guessing you've got your parameters reversed.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint

Comment: ...and also, mMapController.setZoom(18); Are you sure that there are tiles available at zoom 18 for the region in question?

Comment: Wow I feel dumb. I was just copying the coordinates from my kml file which listed the longitude first. Thanks

Comment: No problem, sometimes you just need a fresh set of eyes to look at a problem